First measure with shorter than others in MuseScore
I found this score, as you can see the first measure only has two 16th notes, and the next measure is larger than first.

I was trying to pass this score using MuseScore, but I had to insert a lot of silence to only have two 16ths (equivalent to one 8th).

Is my score fine? if not, How can I fix it?

EDIT:
Secondary click over the measure:

Set the Measure Duration:

Result:


https://musescore.org/en/handbook/4/pickup-and-non-metered-measures

Are you asking about how to create a pickup measure with just two sixteenth notes, or are you asking about how to create the second voice with a "small" note head (read box), or both?

I would like to understand, how is called this situation the Measure... The Red Box is for another question.

You should remove the answer from the question and post it as an answer.

I found this Video in Spanish
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee4s4DGzjl4

Answering your own question is fine, but it should be posted as an answer (not as an edit to the question); please move the Edit part to an answer.

When the first bar of a piece is shorter than the normal bar length, it is called an anacrusis or a pickup. To add an anacrusis, you can change the measure properties (which is what you did), or you can add an anacrusis when creating the score by selecting 'Create pickup measure' in the Additional Score Information menu which is easier.

